# Cannot send daily notfication on android with java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying 1 month now to make a feature witch sends to the user one notification daily at the time the user has selected but when the `onTimeSet()` called i'm getting only this error below and the Notification is not coming to the user

**I try these solutions below:**

- removing all code from `onTimeSet()` & `startAlarm()` inside my activity
- changing `this` to `SetNotificationActivity.this`
- Invalidate chaches / restart

**Error:**

```
E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{838da5a u0 com.george.igrow/com.george.igrow.SetNotificationActivity} has no registered input channel
```

**SetNotificationActivity.java:**

```
public class SetNotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_notification);

        final Button setAlarm = findViewById(R.id.buttonAlarm);
        final Button skip_btn = findViewById(R.id.button4);

        setAlarm.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
            timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
        });

        skip_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(SetNotificationActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        startAlarm(c);
    }

    private void startAlarm(Calendar c) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);

        if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance()))
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        startActivity(new Intent(SetNotificationActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));

    }
}
```

**AlertReceiver.java:**

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, SplashScreenActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Send notification for the current Alarm
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper.getChannelNotification();
        //nb.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, nb.build());


    }
}
```